# Detect new line in codemirror, without overriding default behavior of Enter key

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to detect when the user presses Enter in codemirror. I found this answer: 
[Detecting new line in codemirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469605/detecting-new-line-in-codemirror)

However, when using:

```
extraKeys:{
    Enter: myFunction
}
```

It overrides the default behavior of pressing the enter key, which is "newlineAndIndent", meaning there is no new line created at all.

I would like a function to be called when the user presses enter, whilst keeping the default behaviors of the Enter key. I guess I could just have myFunction to add a newline to the editor, but it is called many times for different reasons, so it isn't very appropriate to have it interact with the editor.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning `CodeMirror.Pass` from a key handler will cause the default behavior (or the next keyhandler) to be run after your handler returns.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted, this is the kind of solution I was looking for, even though aljordan82's was working well. Thanks to both of you.